# Draw.io : How can I debug unminified js code?

Tags: javascript, minify, draw.io

I downloaded draw.io source files from the github repository and tried to make some minor changes to the import function, but all the sources are minified (especially app.min.js).
So my question is this: is there any way to debug the code with the unminified sources?
Also I tried to pass inside the query string the param dev=1, but it gives some errors and doesn't manage to load.

I already saw the post [Draw.io — Is there non-minified source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205746/draw-io-is-there-non-minified-source) but I don't know how to build draw.io.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Draw.io -- Is there non-minified source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205746/draw-io-is-there-non-minified-source)

Comment: with dev=1 the mxgraph repo has to be checked out as a sibling repo to drawio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found, in my opinon, a strange solution.
I took [build.xml](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/blob/master/etc/build/build.xml#L86) file and replaced all the `<jscomp>` instructions with `<concat>` so the result file isn't a minification but just a merge of all source files.

This method works just fine and it solves my problem but i don't know if there is a simpler and more right method.