# how will get Draw.io development source code?

Tags: jgraph, draw.io

How will get below link source code(Draw.io)? Can you help me.

https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/javascript/examples/grapheditor/www/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio), see also:

[Draw.io : How can I debug unminified js code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56026571/draw-io-how-can-i-debug-unminified-js-code/56458484#56458484)

[Draw.io — Is there non-minified source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45205746/draw-io-is-there-non-minified-source)